# Handling Strings with special characters in Java

Tags: java, json, string, escaping, special-characters

I'm implementing a String matching algorithm that requires handling Strings with special characters. On one side of matching, the Strings were prepared in Python, then went through JAVA. On the other side, they were prepared by another environment. Now I'm matching them in my program in Java (Strings retrieved from JSON inputs).

While some of the characters are handled, I have issues handling many others.

For instance, I get a **MATCH** for this (both showed on my console as `>> AS IT COMES CRUMBLING`):

```
"text":"\u003e\u003e AS IT COMES CRUMBLING"
"caption":">> AS IT COMES CRUMBLING"
```

But these ones shown as **NON-MATCH**:

```
"text":"What if you had fewer headaches\nand migraines a month?"
"text":"What if you had fewer headaches\\nand migraines a month?"
```

Or this one:

```
"text":"Effects of BOTOX® may spread"
"text":"Effects of BOTOX\\xc2\\xae may spread"
```

Or this:

```
"text":"Let's also rethink how\nwe care for ourselves."
"text":"Let'\\xe2\\x80\\x99s also rethink how\\nwe care for ourselves."
```

In my code, I use `JSONPath` to read `JSON` inputs from both sides, put them in an `ArrayList`, and then compare one against all items in the list.

```
boolean found=false;
myText foundText = null;
for (int i = 0; i < scheduledText.size(); i++) {
    if(current.text.equals(scheduledText.get(i).text)) {
        found = true;
        foundText =scheduledText.get(i);
        break;
    }
}
if(found)
   //print MATCH
else
   //print NON_MATCH
```

I'm frustrated. What should I do? How can I handle these?

Comment: Could you provide your java code that is saying that the Strings are matching?

Comment: How about writing a function to clean up the string of any special characters and simply keeping ANSI characters then convert to a hash such a md5 hash. compare the two strings(hashes) and if they match you have a match. Unless you need to keep the special characters for some reason.

Comment: @Connor Updated my question. Simply using `String.equals`.

Comment: @Miguel Assuming no solutions, it's fine. But how?!

Comment: Why do you think e.g. the second example ("headaches") should match? The first string contains a `line feed`, the second a `backslash` followed by an `n`. Where do you get the `\\xnn` constructs from? They are non-standard. Interpreted according to the standard, `\\xe2` means four characters, a `backslash`, an `x`, a `e`, and a `2`, although most probably some original source wanted to escape a single byte `e2`.

Comment: The `\\xnn` are also from Java which apparently adds an extra \. Otherwise can not handle \x. But in raw strings, we have \x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for my proposed solution, you would use a function in your java code like below.

```
private static String cleanTextContent(String text)
    {
        // strips off all non-ASCII characters
        text = text.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "");

        // erases all the ASCII control characters
        text = text.replaceAll("[\\p{Cntrl}&&[^\r\n\t]]", "");

        // removes non-printable characters from Unicode
        text = text.replaceAll("\\p{C}", "");

        text = text.replaceAll("[^ -~]","");

        text = text.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");

        text = text.replaceAll("\\\\x\\p{XDigit}{2}", "");

        text = text.replaceAll("\\n","");

        text = text.replaceAll("[^\\x20-\\x7e]", "");
        return text.trim();
    }
```

Once you call this function you can use Apache Commons lib to convert string to md5 hash something like this.

```
private static String hashMyString(String text)  {

    String hashText= text;

    String md5Hex = DigestUtils
      .md5Hex(hashText).toUpperCase();

   return md5Hex;
}
```

Finally just compare the two hashes in your main program.

**Edit:** If using maven this is the library the basically makes the DigestUtils work.

```
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

**Edit:**
My full Test code for String.

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {

       String sideOneString = "Effects of BOTOX® may spread";
       String sideTwoString = "Effects of BOTOX\\xc2\\xae may spread";
       String sideThreeString = "BOTOX injections take about\n15 mins";
       String sideFourString  = "BOTOX\\xc2\\xae injections take about\\n15 mins";


       System.out.println( hashMyString(cleanTextContent(sideOneString)));
       System.out.println( hashMyString(cleanTextContent(sideTwoString)));
       System.out.println( hashMyString(cleanTextContent(sideThreeString)));
       System.out.println( hashMyString(cleanTextContent(sideFourString)));
    }





    private  static  String hashMyString(String text)  {

        String hashText= text;

        String md5Hex = DigestUtils.md5Hex(hashText).toUpperCase();
        //System.out.println(md5Hex);
       return md5Hex;
    }

    private static String cleanTextContent(String text)
    {
        // strips off all non-ASCII characters
        text = text.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "");

        // erases all the ASCII control characters
        text = text.replaceAll("[\\p{Cntrl}&&[^\r\n\t]]", "");

        // removes non-printable characters from Unicode
        text = text.replaceAll("\\p{C}", "");

        text = text.replaceAll("[^ -~]","");

        text = text.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");

        text = text.replaceAll("\\\\x\\p{XDigit}{2}", "");
        text = text.replaceAll("\\\\n","");


        text = text.replaceAll("[^\\x20-\\x7e]", "");
        return text.trim();
    }
}
```

result :

```
F928A529F380EB59575AC8A175FDFE79
F928A529F380EB59575AC8A175FDFE79
B4740299C53E18C9ECAF18BA35151D43
B4740299C53E18C9ECAF18BA35151D43
```

Comment: getting back to this. Can you please leave a comment what each line mean? I actually need to have numbers and basic characters like #$%*. Does this filter them out?